# Javascript object multiple loop, same order?

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I know, that not every browser will output object items in the order they were added when you loop through.
But if I loop through an object a second time, can I be sure, that it will output the items in the same order as before, keeping in mind, that it must not be in the order as they were added?

Comment: Are you sure about your statement?
_not every browser will output object items in the order they were added when you loop through_

Comment: @halafi: There's no guarantee about the order in which `for-in` iterates property names at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if I loop through an object a second time, can I be sure, that it will output the items in the same order as before...

Not if you modify the object in any way. And even if you don't, then you're relying on undocumented behavior, since there are **no** guarantees about the order that properties are visited, including no guarantee they'll be visited in the same order subsequent times.

If you need something reliable, consider using `Object.keys` and `sort`:

```
Object.keys(theObject).sort().forEach(function(key) {
    // The order here will reliably be alphabetical
});
```

Note that `Object.keys` is in all modern browsers, but not in older ones like IE8. It can easily be polyfilled, though.

Live Example:

```js
var obj1 = {};
obj1.a = 1;
obj1.b = 2;
obj1.c = 3;
Object.keys(obj1).sort().forEach(function(key) {
  snippet.log(key);
});

var obj2 = {};
obj2.c = 3;
obj2.b = 2;
obj2.a = 1;
Object.keys(obj2).sort().forEach(function(key) {
  snippet.log(key);
});
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Okay I guess I'll use something like this to ensure correct item order. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, I think it will but you can make sure that it will do that if you use a sorted keys array like so:

```
var keys = Object.keys(myObject).sort();

keys.forEach(function (key) {
  // Access the value
  myObject[key]
});
```